# Como criar uma AVD para Android em Delphi

Tags: android, delphi

Estou começando no Delphi® XE5 e gostaria de saber como faço para configurar/criar uma AVD para emular aplicações Android. Só me dá a opção de escolher o aparelho, mas não tenho nada em Target do Android SDK 22.0.1.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar o `AVD Manager` que é um aplicativo da Google que você encontra em conjunto com a `ADT Bundle` que é um conjunto de aplicativos utilizados para gerenciar e utilizar o Android.

## [Aqui você pode fazer o download do ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Direto do site da Android Developers.

O uso do aplicativo é realmente simples, você só precisa abrir o AVD Manager e você terá uma lista de AVD's que você possui, você pode edita-los ou criar um novo, informando as configurações do mesmo e o modelo/versão da SDK utilizada.

## Observação muito importante:

Você precisa abrir o `SDK Manager` e atualizar as determinadas versões do Android que você pretende utilizar! pois sem elas atualizadas você não pode criar um AVD com tal versão.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar o AVD no próprio aplicativo fornecido pelo Google. Após a criação ele aparecerá ai.

Outra coisa, você pode utilizar seu próprio aparelho para fazer os testes. Basta ativar o modo desenvolvedor no seu aparelho, depois disso, ao plugar o aparelho na USB do pc ele irá aparecer como um AVD (tenho um Galaxy Ace e não precisou de nenhum driver para isto).

Fiz uma pequena aplicação no Delphi XE5 e realmente funcionou no iOS, Android e Windows.